# Chef-solo 12.1.1 usermod: user www-data is currently used by process 801

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, chef-solo

Provisioning of a custom cookbook fails on a users_manage resource:

users_manage "www-data" do
    action :create
end

The reason is that this user is currently running the nginx worker process.

A simple fix should be to stop the service while users_manage is running. What is the best way to do this in Chef?

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be something like:

```
service 'nginx' do
  action :stop
  only_if ... # (add your condition check here, like a `ps` call to get the user of the nginx process)
end

users_manage 'www-data' do 
  action :create
end

service 'nginx' do
  action :start
end
```

A better way would probably be to backfill the data bag for the `users` cookbook to keep it in sync with the current system so it won't change anything, given that you first call the `users` cookbook and later install nginx (in the run_list).

An even better way would be to add your custom users to the www-group and leave nginx alone. Nginx's user/group memberships are defined by the package/distro and various things assume specific settings, e.g. logrotate cronjobs. If you change that, you'll probably gonna have a bad time…